# Hibernate creating wrong create table statement?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

It's my first time configuring hibernate. I've read many tutorials but not sure why this is creating the wrong create table sql statement. I am using PostgreSQL as my database.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://DBIP:5432/MYDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">MYDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">MYPASS</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="MYPROJ.model.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

User.java

```
package MYPROJ.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User
{
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "age")
  private int age;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setAge(20);
        user.setUsername("david");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);


        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Done!");

    }
}
```

When I run the program it shows the following SQL statement for creating the table which does not work when I run the program or when I copy pasted it manually

```
create table User (id int4 not null, age int4, username varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Two things that I can think of, first User is a reserved word in Postgres and many other database. Second you can try using Integer instead of int

Comment: i agree as well you should use Integer instead of int , because in  hibernate column type must be a class.

Comment: problem was user was a reserved word in postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that "user" was a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL, changing that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell hibernate your column name must be escaped to avoid conflicts with the database keywords. To do that, enclose the name between `. Example:

```
@Column(name="`user`")
```